# Using CASE WHEN to assign buckets

Tags: sql, t-sql

Fairly new to coding. I've created a new column that outputs the days a task is overdue using DateDiff. I then want to take the result of the DateDiff and assign it an expression (>60 days overdue, 30-45 days overdue, etc.) using CASE WHEN. However, this errors out, specifically saying that there's an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE"

```
SELECT t.name, t.Task,DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate()) As DaysOverdue
CASE WHEN DaysOverdue >= 60 THEN '>60 days Overdue'
     WHEN DaysOverdue <=45 And >=30 THEN '30-45 days Overdue'
     ELSE 'Current' END as bucket
FROM t
```

I want it to create a new column called 'bucket' that shows the result of the CASE WHEN expression

```
name   task      Daysoverdue         bucket

  x       y            43            30-45 days overdue
  a       b            64            >60 days overdue
```

Comment: Aside: Usually buckets are assigned so that they are contiguous, e.g. ">60", "46 to 60", "30 to 45" and "Current". Since `case` checks the `when` clauses in order you can check for `> 60`, `> 45`, `> 30` and `else` catches current accounts. There is no need to use `between`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a comma (,) after DaysOverdue

also do not use DaysOverdue alias in the case, use `DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate())`

you cannot use > and < this way `WHEN DaysOverdue <=45 And >=30` instead use

```
WHEN DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate()) between 30 And 45
```

This is how it should be in the end

```
SELECT t.name, t.Task,DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate()) As DaysOverdue,
CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate())>= 60 THEN '>60 days Overdue'
     WHEN DateDiff(day, t.DueDate, GetDate()) between 30 And 45 THEN '30-45 days Overdue'
     ELSE 'Current' END as bucket
FROM t
```